# Type casting in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, casting, python-2.7

How do I cast a float into long in Python 2.7?

I'm doing the same in Python 2.3 like this:

```
from array import*
data = array('L',[12.34])
print data
```

which prints out:

```
array('L',[12L])
```

How do I do the same in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this?

```
>>> long(12.34)
12L
```

Comment: The use of the `array` module is to create memory-efficient arrays of homogeneous type.  I've got a feeling I'm missing something about your question.

Answer (score 2):

These days, it is much more common to see `numpy` arrays than arrays from the `array` module, however, your array can be constructed as:

```
>>> from array import *
>>> array('L',map(long,[12.34]))
array('L', [12L])
```

with numpy, it could be done as:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([12.34],dtype=long)
```

However, this doesn't actually create python longs, it actually creates an array of `np.int64` integers (8 byte ints -- Not arbitrary precision like python long).

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1.1,2.2]
data = map(long,lst)
```